# Multiplyuser input by odd numbers C++

Tags: c++, user-input

I need to write a program that takes input from the user and **multiplies** it by numbers: 3, 5, 7, and 9. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int N;

std::cout << "Input a number: ";
std::cin >> N;

int limit = 9;

for(int i = 3; i <= limit; ++i)
{
    if(i % 2 != 0) // if odd
    {
        N = N * i;
        std::cout << N << std::endl;
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

When I output this code, it displays:

```
Input a number: 1 
3
15
105
945
```

However, what I am aiming for is this:

```
Input a number: 1 
3
5
7
9
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should re-assign `N` after you print its value, otherwise you just do `1*3*5*7*9`

Comment: The answer below is correct, however this is a good time to learn to use the debugger step by step and evaluate the variables.

Comment: `takes input from the user and multiplies it by numbers: 3, 5, 7, and 9` your code actually does this in a certain way: `N *= 3*5*7*9`. I think you need to get very specific in terms of what you really want. That needs to be clear first before writing the code.

Comment: @bean, I saw your expected output, which certainly helps (both you and me), but I think you lost some of that clarity while writing your code, which I thought may be due to confusing the goal.

Answer (score 2):

You over write your variable `N` at `N = N * i`. You should add a second variable to output your result and not overwrite your input.

Tip: You increment your loop by just one with `++i`. If you replace that with `i+=2` you only loop over the desired multiplication numbers. At this point you can also leave out the if statement.

Comment: +1 from me, but I think a second variable isn't needed. We can actually get *rid of* `limit` and replace the whole for loop with this: `for(int i = 3; i <= 9; i += 2) std::cout << N*i << std::endl;`

Comment: @ellliott O yes I did not notice the limit variable. We are working a lot with MISRA code so it is not allowed to have magic numbers. I just assumed it was a constexpr.